# Why command line cannot display English words soundmark?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I developed a tool to display the words soundmark. I know the soundmark should be some special charset, I guess the charset should be 'unicode', but I am not sure.

My program runs well in IDE(IntelliJ) on Windows, but it shows crazy displaying if running in the command line both Windows and Linux.

Running this code in Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "/ˈpɒz.ə.tɪv/";
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

The display on Linux will like

```
/藞p蓲z.蓹.t瑟v/
```

I execute 'locale' on this EC2

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Some people advice use 'UTF-8' or PrintStream. But I test the following code, does not work.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String x = "/ˈpɒz.ə.tɪv/";
        byte[] bs =x.getBytes(Charset.forName("unicode"));
        String y = new String(bs, "unicode");
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        System.out.println("y = " + y);
        String z = "\u00C6\u00D8\u00C5";
        System.out.println("z = " + z);
        StringBuilder persianHello = new StringBuilder("سلام");
        PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        outStream.println("Hello world!");
        outStream.println(persianHello); // Renders backwards in console, but correctly in the IDE.
        byte directionality = Character.getDirectionality(persianHello.charAt(0));
        if (directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC) {
            outStream.println("Reversed string:" + persianHello.reverse()); // Renders correctly in console, but backwards in the IDE...
        }
    }
```

The output in IDE is fine, but in command line is:

```
x = /?p?z.?.t?v/
y = /?p?z.?.t?v/
z = ???
爻賱丕賲
```

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you run `locale` on your EC2 system and include the output as a code block?

Comment: @bk2204 I add the result of 'locale', thanks your reminder